# Conversion of numpy array to bytearray

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

Why is this difference between these two codes?:-

```
In [45]: import cv2

In [46]: cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

In [47]: r, f = cap.read()

In [48]: cap.release()

In [49]: f.shape
Out[49]: (480, 640, 3)

In [50]: f = cv2.resize(f, (640, 480))

In [51]: f.shape
Out[51]: (480, 640, 3)

In [55]: frame = f.reshape(1, 640*480*3)
In [56]: frame.shape
Out[56]: (1, 921600)
In [57]: p = bytearray(frame)
In [59]: len(p)
Out[59]: 921600
In [61]: frame
Out[61]: array([[19, 51, 57, ..., 19, 40, 46]], dtype=uint8)
```

Now I took another numpy array:-

```
In [62]: l = np.arange(1, 100)
In [64]: l.shape
Out[64]: (99,)
In [65]: np.expand_dims(l, axis=0)
In [68]: l.shape
Out[68]: (1, 99)
```

As u can see, its shape is similar to that of frame, but when I convert it to byte array as follows:-

```
In [69]: len(bytearray(l))
Out[69]: 792
```

Why is it that the length is coming out to be different?
Afterall the shapes of frame and l are similar?

Please explain the algorithm of conversion of numpy array to bytearray.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) function uses `np.int64` as the datatype when no `dtype` argument is explicitly given and your values "look like" integers:

> If dtype is not given, infer the data type from the other input arguments.

This then has 64 bits aka 8 bytes per element, which gives you `99 * 8 = 792` bytes when converted into a `bytearray`.

To get one byte per element, pass in a suitable `dtype`, for example:

```
l = np.arange(1, 100, dtype=np.uint8)
print(l.dtype)    # to be totally sure
```

Which ofc requires your data to fit into the `0..255` interval, but that's the case here.

Many of the `numpy` array factories like `np.zeros`, `np.empty`, `np.ones`, and also many of its array conversion functions support the `dtype` kwarg, so you're in control of what you're working with.

Comment: Thanks, understood the concept!!